# cannot find modules in node js application even though modules are installed

Tags: node.js, express

> my project directory is as follows.

```
project
|
└───.github
└───build 
└───contracts
└───migrations
└───node_modules
└───src
│   │  index.html    
│   └───css 
│   └───js 
|        | app.js
|        | bootstrap.min.js
|        | web3.min.js
|        | truffle-contract.js
│   └───images    
│   └───fonts
└───test
 bs-config.json
 package.json
 package-lock.json
 truffle-config.js
```

> whenever I run my project using `npm run dev` my website is opening. But I am not able to access modules that are installed. On the console, I am getting error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
```

In `app.js` file

`var express=require('express');`

> I installed express using

`npm install -g express`

and in node modules folder I can see express folder.
But I am not able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your app.js is not at the same directory of your node_modules folder. What every your root node app file is, it should be at the same directorial level of node_modules folder.

Or you can create a file called server.js in your root directory that calls app.js, check the following hierarchy:

```
project
|
└───.github
└───build 
└───contracts
└───migrations
└───node_modules
└───src
│   │  index.html    
│   └───css 
│   └───js 
|        | app.js
|        | bootstrap.min.js
|        | web3.min.js
|        | truffle-contract.js
│   └───images    
│   └───fonts
└───test
└───server.js
 bs-config.json
 package.json
 package-lock.json
 truffle-config.js
```

Comment: Getting following error on console.` Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/server.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`

Comment: why do you try to load this url "localhost:3000/server.js"? You have 2 options:
1) just run `node server.js` on application root folder.
2) add it in your scripts in your package.json file and run `npm start`

Comment: I used npm run dev and website index.html loaded and in my index.html file I mentioned script tag.`<script  src="../server.js"></script>`

Comment: You can not do that. server.js is a server side file. You should not call it in ah HTML template. In server you define your routes with express and inside the routes you can send a response that loads in html. Check the first snippet of code in this link:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files